# Too many join statement in SQL

Tags: postgresql, join

The following code is to heavy to run and I would appreciate your help to make it lighter. It is PSQL and it basically join the main table to many subtable to gather required data. I would like to know if it's possible to join only once instead of twice. The current code gives the desired output. Is there a way to divide the number of join by 2?

```
select u1.id, u2.id, s1.is_sys, s2.is_sys, ft.created_at, ft.currency, ft.gross_amount, ft.from_acc_id, ft.to_acc_id, 
u1.app_id as from_app_id, u2.app_id as to_app_id
from main_cry_transac ft

 JOIN crypto_accounts fa1 ON fa1.id = ft.from_acc_id
 JOIN crypto_accounts fa2 ON fa2.id = ft.to_acc_id
 
 JOIN main_users u1 ON u1.id = fa1.user_id 
 JOIN main_users u2 ON u2.id = fa2.user_id 
 
 join main_user_settings s1 ON s1.user_id = u1.id
 join main_user_settings s2 ON s2.user_id = u2.id
 
 where u1.app_id <> u2.app_id
```

Comment: Have you looked into indexing your tables?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way to write this query, and unless one of the involved tables is very small, this is always going to be slow, no matter how you index the tables.

But the query will produce many result rows, right? So the duration is justified.

If you want to speed up execution, add additional `WHERE` conditions that restrict the number of rows and appropriate indexes.

Comment: We don't know the constraints, and when constraints hold some expressions return the same as others that otherwise wouldn't. So it's possible that if constraints hold but are not declared then the user could find a faster phrasing relying on them, and it's possible that if all constraints become declared then the DBMS can optimize the query as is. Similarly indexes make a huge difference & we don't know them either. We need a [mre].

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thank you for your answer. I could understand that I should find other ways than the join statements to streamline it.